# I rewrote script to function, but it does not work properly

Tags: python, image-processing

I have created a script named "vertical filter" that detects the vertical part of an image, distinguishes it from the horizontal part, and creates a new image by dividing it into black and white.
The script can produce the image I want, but when I rewrite it as a function, it does not work properly. I know that my rewriting method is wrong, but I don't know how to rewrite it, so I asked my question here. Below is the original script and the image created from it. The black and white image is the result I am looking for, and the color image is the original image and the result of the function.

Original script:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import data, io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
!pip install scikit-image

img = io.imread('data/earth.jpg')
verical_filter =[[-1,-2,-1],[0,0,0],[1,2,1]] 
n,m,d= img.shape #get the current shape of image/an array

#with vertical filter
vertical_edges_img = np.zeros_like(img) 
for row in range(3, n-2): #loop every single pixels
    for col in range(3, m-2):
        local_pixels = img[row-1:row+2,col-1:col+2,1] 
        transformed_pixels = verical_filter * local_pixels
        vertical_score = (transformed_pixels.sum() +4)/8 
   
    vertical_edges_img[row, col] = [vertical_score] * 3

plt.imshow(vertical_edges_img)
```

[image with vertical filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hG66.png)

Rewritten as function:

```
def vertical_img(img):
    verical_filter =[[-1,-2,-1],[0,0,0],[1,2,1]] 
    n,m,d= img.shape #get the current shape of image/an array

    vertical_edges_img = np.zeros_like(img) 
    upsidedown_pic = np.array(img)
    for row in range(3, n-2): #loop every single pixels
        for col in range(3, m-2):
            local_pixels = img[row-1:row+2,col-1:col+2,1]
            transformed_pixels = verical_filter * local_pixels
            vertical_score = (transformed_pixels.sum() +4)/8 
        
        
            vertical_edges_img[row, col] = [vertical_score] * 3

    return upsidedown_pic


vert_img = vertical_img(img)
plt.imshow(vert_img)
```

[picture through the function. It is also original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0bxT.jpg)

Comment: You need to indent the code inside the function, the way you have it now will give you a syntax error. Please copy-paste the function exactly the way you have written it.

Comment: Then also please clarify “it does not work properly”. You need to describe exactly how the results differ from what you expect. Otherwise we’ll be guessing at your actual problem.

Comment: If `vertical_edges_img` is the result image, you probably want to `return vertical_edges_img` at the end of your function.

Comment: Your function builds and returns an `upsidedown_pic`. It seems like its calculations are simply ignored. The two bits of code do different things, so different results.

Comment: You should return vertical_edges_img not upsidedown_pic in vertical_img(img) and img = io.imread('data/earth.jpg') should be set.